# Issue in using ionic view app and setting my project git

Tags: ionic-framework, view

I have an issue when I am running git push ionic master in my command prompt. I am getting this error :

> src spec ref master does not match any , failed to push some ref to ‘git@git...’

I have followed all the steps in ionic view manual.

Comment: can you post the link for the ionic view manual ?

Comment: This is the link : https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/view/

Comment: Did you create your channel? What is the master URL of the new repository you got from ionic ?

Comment: I didn’t understand where to create my channel in my code? Can you help me with this? Because no documentation are found

Comment: I have the same issue. Documentation sucks IMO.

Comment: Yes this is so hard is there any other solution to do it?

Comment: Same issue, we stuck at "Connect your app" step. The app is connected but Ionic dashboard dint recognize this.